# cross-domain policy error in Silverlight with WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I'm getting the following error when I connect my Silverlight app to my WCF service. I host this wcf as a self host service.

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://lmr-hero/iSponsorWebSite/projectService.svc/basic'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

What are the possible reasons for this error?

Comment: Where is your service being hosted?

Comment: Actually, first I hosted it as a self host service. But since i cant find a place to  put that two xml files (clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml) when i'm hosting it as self hosted service, I hosted it in IIS server and put that two xml's in to my 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot'. Then it worked perfectly. thx for the support to everyone !

Comment: In local machine its working fine. but when I deployed WCF in IIS on server then its not working. its throwing the same error. When I'm trying to open crossdomain.xml its not opening on server . It says 'Unspecified error Error processing resource 'http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd'. '

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Silverlight application is not hosted on the same domain as the service then you will need to put a clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomain.xml file on the server that hosts the service.

See this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I put that both xml files in to my 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot' and it's worked. thx for the support :D

Comment: I had this problem when both my Silverlight app and WCF service were hosted in Visual Studio with ASP.NET Development Server (i.e. not hosted in IIS). To fix it I had to change the Virtual Path for the WCF host web site to /. The reason why is because Silverlight looks for clientaccesspolicy.xml in the root of the domain that hosts the service. To change the Virtual Path, right click on the web site and choose Properties.

Comment: In local machine its working fine. but when I deployed WCF in IIS on server then its not working. its throwing the same error. When I'm trying to open crossdomain.xml its not opening on server . It says 'Unspecified error Error processing resource 'http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd'. '

Answer (score 2):

Right click the .svc file and hit view in browser. Check to see if it's even being hosted and running correctly first. That will give you a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you set up a WCF web service correctly in Silverlight, when using Silverlight to consume the web service.  Unlike a console mode client, in Silverlight you cannot just create a WCF New Item in your Solution, but must, under the .Web portion of your Silverlight solution, right-click, Add a New Item that is called "Silverlight-enabled WCF Service".  Now you can go to the Silverlight app folder, add a Service Reference and you will not get this run-time error. This will avoid the run-time error the original poster refers to.