# error writing file on remote server in WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight, file

I'm creating a WCF (C#, VS2010) for my silverlight app, I'm trying to create a file on my remote server (where WCF exists), but I get an unknown error, I just get "Server not found" error in WCF function complete exception message, I use following codes to create a file on my remote server (I use a VDS, so I think I don't have permission problems, I use remote desktop on my server)

```
            using (StreamWriter outfile =
            new StreamWriter("mytest.htm"))
            {
                outfile.Write(body);
            }
```

what is going wrong here? is it possible that I have permission problems? I run my WCF on local system and it creates file successfully, but there is no luck when it is uploaded to remote server

should I use Server.MapPath for giving address of my file?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449797/cross-domain-policy-error-in-silverlight-with-wcf?rq=1

Comment: thanks but my WCF and silverlight are running without any problems, I have copied these 2 XML files, my problem is creating a file on my remote server

Comment: You have enough permissions on the server right?

Comment: perhaps it is my problem, but how can I know it? I use remote desktop to connect to my server, so I suppose I have enough permissions, right? it is Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Can you try using a absolute path? like C:\SomeFolder\mytest.htm? Because I have done this. And what is the size of the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: I had tested an absolute path, but with the same result, my file is very small indeed! just some characters

Comment: try this example : http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/01/06/file-uploader-using-silverlight-and-wcf/

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
        System.Net.FileWebRequest request = (System.Net.FileWebRequest)System.Net.FileWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri("\\\\remotelocation\\MyText.txt"));
        request.Method = "POST";

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();  
        byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test_content"); 
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);  

        requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain ***why***, simple code answers are not acceptable on SO as they do not help people understand what they were doing wrong and why.